# Differentiate h1 tags to be used in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have two **h1 tags** with content **heading** and **second heading**.

My problem is that when use jquery `both the h1 tags get activated`.

I `want the Second heading only to be used in jquery`.  How do i achieve it?

```js
 function animateText() {
            TweenMax.from($('h1'), 0.8, {
                scale: 0.4,
                opacity: 0,
                rotation: 15,
                ease: Back.easeOut.config(4),
            });
        }
```

```html
<h1 >Heading</h1>

<h1 >second heading</h1>
```

Comment: It's **well worth** your time reading through [the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/) beginning to end. It only takes about an hour, two tops, and it pays you back almost immediately in time saved because of the knowledge you gain.

Comment: If tags are is your HTML code, you should identify by an `id`. If the tags are generated dynamically, use a selector that you are sure it will identify your `h1` despite possible outcomes, of generated code -> using `eq` is not such a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can add id tags to the elements :

```
<h1 id="not_using">Heading</h1>

<h1 id="use_this_one">second heading</h1>
```

Then identify them by their id.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`:contains` selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/):

```
TweenMax.from($('h1:contains(Second)')//...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) in this case

```js
function animateText() {
            TweenMax.from($('h1 + h1'), 0.8, {
                scale: 0.4,
                opacity: 0,
                rotation: 15,
                ease: Back.easeOut.config(4),
            });
        }
        
animateText();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.0.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<h1 >Heading</h1>

<h1 >second heading</h1>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use **[:eq() Selector](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)** as follow if you don't want to use any id for the second **h1** tag

```
 function animateText() {
        TweenMax.from( $('h1:eq(1)'), 0.8, { //You can also use $('h1').eq(1)
            scale: 0.4,
            opacity: 0,
            rotation: 15,
            ease: Back.easeOut.config(4),
        });
    }
```